How to do an if statement with the .MigrateAsync() method?
I use this code at the moment:
public static class DataHelper
{
    public static async Task ManageDataAsync(IServiceProvider svcProvider)
    {
        var dbContextSvc = svcProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();

        await dbContextSvc.Database.MigrateAsync();
    }
}

And I call:
await DataHelper.ManageDataAsync(scope.ServiceProvider);

In the Program.cs class.
The problem is that when I run the app for the first time, if the DB wasn't updated yet, it runs perfectly, however when I run it the second time after the DB has been updated, it breaks and says the DB has already been updated.
How can I have an if statement that would update the DB only if it hasn't been updated and to ignore this call if it has ?

Unrelated: you need to dispose dbContextSvc before ManageDataAsync completes.

You can use GetPendingMigrationsAsync to check for any pending migrations and skip the MigrateAsync invocation if there aren't any:
public static class DataHelper
{
    public static async Task ManageDataAsync( IServiceProvider sp, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default )
    {
        if( sp is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof(sp) );

        //

        using AppDbContext db = sp.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();

        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.getpendingmigrationsasync
        IEnumerable<String> pendingMigrationIds = await db.Database.GetPendingMigrationsAsync( cancellationToken ).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if( pendingMigrationIds.Any() )
        {
            await db.Database.MigrateAsync( cancellationToken ).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}


As an editorial, I'm disappointed that GetPendingMigrationsAsync returns IEnumerable<String> (representing a possibly-empty, possibly-nonmaterialized collection of migration-identifiers) which doesn't expose a synchronous .Count property, so you have to use Linq's .Any() instead - or materialize it to a concrete in-memory collection, neither of which are appealing to me.

I see, and why would you use .ConfigureAwait(false) in this case ?

@CodingIsFunYouShouldTryIt Because the ManageDataAsync method doesn't appear to need a synchronization-context, so adding ConfigureAwait(false) allows the async continuation to run on the next-available thread (i.e. sooner) without waiting for a spot to open-up in the synchronized context.

Ok so I tried the code but it still says stuff like There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database where I thought this code would prevent that by not trying to run anything it doesn't need to run. What should I do then ? Thank you
